# No "close session" on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, optical-drive, cd-burning

Any ideas what would cause Windows 7 to not display the "Close Session" button?

Colleague burned a CD in XP and didn't have an option to finalize the CD.  I've also looked on my machine (Windows 7) and I do not have a "close session" button.

I have already looked at:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/where-is-the-close-session-on-the-burner-toolbar/ce024c63-8d9e-44ae-b3aa-8e402699836d

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly was unsatisfactory about the answer posted on `Answers.Microsoft.com`? Did you read this: ***"... if the disc was formatted using the Mastered Format, the option to close a session will not appear as discs formatted with the Mastered Format do not need to be closed and are automatically compatible with other computers."*** ?

Comment: I read it - The disc needs to be closed and it wasn't.  The option was never available.  I believe it's an admin issue preventing me from having this

Comment: @iglvzx I have a disc which is multi-session.  I know this because I have added to it multiple times, and windows reads it fine.  I believe that makes it a Live FS disc by MS terms.  I try to use it in another computer and that computer cannot determine the filesystem of the disc.  The disc was supposed to be a single session closed disc.  I mean that the session should be closed, then the disc should be finalized.  It is not working that way.  And the "Close Session" option is not present in Windows Explorer.  Therefore, there obviously exists a 3rd possibility.

Answer (score -2):

This is a windows problem, it is a known issue for windows 7. Best solution is to not use windows to burn CDs/DVDs and use another piece of software. Unfortunately there is no way to recover the CD/DVD that you just burnt. it is now a coaster.

Comment: Any references to the known issue?